# Anaconda Install: Problem with spaces

Tags: command-line, software-installation, anaconda

I am new to this site, so please redirect if not appropriate.

I am trying to install Anaconda in ubuntu. I want to install it on a particular path as instructed on their [guide](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-linux.html). The problem is with the path specification. I have ensured that the immediate path to the install folder does not contain any spaces. But I get

*ERROR: Cannot install into directories with spaces*

Now, I figured maybe any directories on the path (may not be directly entering the path name) must not contain any spaces. Is this true? In this case, I would have to manually change folder names for all! Additionally this does not seem to be true since there maybe a lot of nested folders and that would be a really cumbersome task. Any solutions or insights? I am learning this thing on the go. Any suggestions would be welcome!

Update: Path used is

```
export PATH="/home/<user>/Work/Anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Update2: Running

```
echo $PATH
```

gives

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:/home/<user>/bin:/home/<user>/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Please tell us the path that you actually tried.

Comment: I have written the command I am using

Comment: @edwinksl hey...i would really appreciate some help

Comment: Did you literally use `<user>`?

Comment: nope my name ofcourse...the problem is I cannot find what spaces it is referring to...I can do a default path install but I wanna learn

Comment: Hmm okay. Do `echo $PATH` and write its output in your question.

Comment: What is the name of the directory in which you saved the Anaconda installer?

Comment: home/<user>/Work/Anaconda/
this place

Comment: This is a pretty weird problem. I suggest you file a bug report with Anaconda while you wait for an answer here. There is nothing inherently wrong with using spaces in paths, and Anaconda should have been able to handle them.

Comment: well thanks...I appreciate the help...keep up the good work ;)

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: Cannot install into directories with spaces?
just like this

```
 bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -p your dir
```

I have solved this problem Good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).